# Unsupported Argument while creating azure vpn gateway

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

**Objective**: Trying to create Azure vpn gateway with AAD authencation type with Terraform

**Code I am using:**
**Azure Rm version:** `2.99`
**Main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw" {
  name = "vng-${var.env}-we"
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  type = "Vpn"
  vpn_type = "RouteBased"
  active_active = true
  enable_bgp = false
  sku = "VpnGw1AZ"
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip.id    
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
  }
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig1"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip-secondary.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
  }
  ip_configuration {
    name = "vnetGatewayConfig2"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip-vpn.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
  }
  vpn_client_configuration {
    address_space = ["xx.xxx.xx/24"]
    vpn_authentication_types = ["AAD"]
    tenant_uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    audience_id = "41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4"
    aad_issuer_uri = "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I am getting error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 834, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw":
│  834:     vpn_authentication_types = ["AAD"]
│ 
│ An argument named "vpn_authentication_types" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 835, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw":
│  835:     tenant_uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/************************************"
│ 
│ An argument named "tenant_uri" is not expected here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 836, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw":
│  836:     audience_id = "41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4"
│ 
│ An argument named "audience_id" is not expected here.
```

Reference Documentation:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5079

Please help how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `azurerm version: 2.99` so you should use related [Terraform azurerm documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/2.99.0/docs/resources/virtual_network_gateway)

Your errors could be resolved if you use:

- `vpn_auth_types` instead of `vpn_authentication_types`
- `aad_tenant` instead of `tenant_uri`
- `aad_audience` instead of `audience_id`
- `aad_issuer` instaed of `aad_issuer_uri`

  ```
  resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "vpn-gw" {
     name = "vng-${var.env}-we"
     location = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
     resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
     type = "Vpn"
     vpn_type = "RouteBased"
     active_active = true
     enable_bgp = false
     sku = "VpnGw1AZ"
     ip_configuration {
       name = "vnetGatewayConfig"
       public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip.id    
       private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
       subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
     }
     ip_configuration {
       name = "vnetGatewayConfig1"
       public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip-secondary.id
       private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
       subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
     }
     ip_configuration {
       name = "vnetGatewayConfig2"
       public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.vpn-gateway-ip-vpn.id
       private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
       subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.gw_snet[0].id
     }
     vpn_client_configuration {
       address_space = ["xx.xxx.xx/24"]
       vpn_auth_types = ["AAD"]
       aad_tenant = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
       aad_audience = "41b23e61-6c1e-4545-b367-cd054e0ed4b4"
       aad_issuer = "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     }
   }
  ```

Comment: Oh no... i missed it.. its different for 2.99.. Let me try this

Comment: It worked.. thanks for guidance, any how I have new issue, I just realized my address space is wrong in vnet (total 4 address spaces) when i change values it does not reflect in terraform plan, anyhow I will raise separate issue